# Oracle table type to nested table cast error

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle10g

I declared table type and set a value in it with using loop. I am having an error while I was casting this t_table

```
DECLARE

  TYPE t_row IS RECORD 
  (
    id  NUMBER,
    description VARCHAR2(50)
  );

  TYPE t_table IS TABLE OF t_row;
  l_tab t_table := t_table();

BEGIN

  FOR i IN 1 .. 10 LOOP
    l_tab.extend();
    l_tab(l_tab.last).id := i;
    l_tab(l_tab.last).description := 'Description for ' || i;
  END LOOP;

  SELECT * from TABLE(CAST(l_tab AS t_table)); 

END
```

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to do a select onto the the type? You would use the the `TABLE()` and the `CAST` rather if you have a collection in a column stored in a table.

You could just loop through the table in your code. Example:

```
  for i in l_tab.first .. l_tab.last
  loop
     dbms_output.put_line(l_tab(i).id||' '||l_tab(i).description);
  end loop;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `l_tab` is of type `t_table`, there's no need for the `cast`. But that's not your problem.

Your problem is that you're trying to reference a PL/SQL type in SQL, which you simply can't do. You can either remove the `select` as @hol suggested or make the type a database object (which will allow SQL to access it):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_row AS OBJECT
(
   id NUMBER,
   description VARCHAR2 (50)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_table AS TABLE OF t_row;

DECLARE
   l_tab t_table := t_table ();
BEGIN
   FOR i IN 1 .. 10 LOOP
      l_tab.EXTEND ();
      l_tab (l_tab.LAST) := t_row (i, 'Description for ' || i);
   END LOOP;

   FOR r IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE (l_tab)) LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (r.id);
   END LOOP;
END;
```

---

There is a second problem with the initial code, in that you are running a `select` without telling the code what to do with it. Unlike some other procedural SQL extensions, PL/SQL does not allow you to implicitly return a handle to a resultset (prior to 12c). You must either handle it directly or explicitly return a `ref_cursor` that points to it. The code above has been update to primitively handle the result of the query.

Comment: The `select *  from ...` won't compile.